# Can we remove dictionary from list based on 2 conditions?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

below is the list of dictionary as output data -

```
[
 {'id':'4y','last_updated': Timestamp('2021-05-12 18:04:00'),'name':'S1'},
 {'id':'5y','last_updated': Timestamp('2021-05-12 18:04:00'),'name':'S2'},
 {'id':'4y','last_updated': Timestamp('2021-05-12 18:01:00'),'name':'S1'},
 {'id':'5y','last_updated': Timestamp('2021-05-12 18:03:00'),'name':'S2'},
 {'id':'4y','last_updated': Timestamp('2021-05-12 18:02:00'),'name':'S1'},
]
```

desired output required is -

```
[
 {'id':'4y','last_updated': Timestamp('2021-05-12 18:04:00'),'name':'S1'},
 {'id':'5y','last_updated': Timestamp('2021-05-12 18:04:00'),'name':'S2'}
]
```

Since we require this to remove the dictionary with same id and name but keep the most recent one, how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `lst` is your list from the question:

```py
out = {}
for d in lst:
    if d["id"] in out:
        if out[d["id"]]["last_updated"] < d["last_updated"]:
            out[d["id"]] = d
    else:
        out[d["id"]] = d

print(list(out.values()))
```

Prints:

```py
[{'id': '4y', 'last_updated': Timestamp('2021-05-12 18:04:00'), 'name': 'S1'}, 
 {'id': '5y', 'last_updated': Timestamp('2021-05-12 18:04:00'), 'name': 'S2'}]
```